# jmeter - How can I store data from first request and pass it to second request using java code

Tags: java, jmeter

I've created a simple test plan in GUI mode, it contains 3 HTTP requests and **"Create cart"** response contains **"id"** that I need to pass as a path param to the request of **"Update cart"**.
 
I've used the JSON extractor to extract and store this variable and in GUI mode everything works just fine. I access the variable via ${token}

[image: test plan structure]

The issue I have - I don't know how to extract, store and access the stored variable from the java code. I played around with JsonPostProcessor but seems like I use it incorrectly.
 Kindly see the code below:

```
    ...

    HashTree testPlanContainer = new HashTree();

    HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
    headerManager.add(new Header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token));
    headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
    headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HeaderPanel.class.getName());

    HTTPSampler createCustomer = new HTTPSampler();
    ...set domain, method, body, etc

    HTTPSampler createCart = new HTTPSampler();
    ...set domain, method, body, etc

    JSONPostProcessor jsonPostProcessor = new JSONPostProcessor();
    jsonPostProcessor.setRefNames("cart-id");
    jsonPostProcessor.setJsonPathExpressions("$.id");
    jsonPostProcessor.process();

    HashTree composeCreateCartWithJsonExtractor = new HashTree();
    composeCreateCartWithJsonExtractor.add(createCart, jsonPostProcessor);

    HTTPSampler updateCart = new HTTPSampler();
    updateCart.setPath("path"  + ${cart-id}); //how can I access this variable from java code?
    ... set domain, method, body, etc

    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    ... set details

    SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
    ... set details

    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("My test plan");
    ...set details 

    testPlanContainer.add(testPlan);

    HashTree composer = testPlanContainer.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
    composer.add(headerManager);
    composer.add(createCustomer);
    composer.add(composeCreateCartWithJsonExtractor);
    composer.add(updateCart);

    SaveService.saveTree(testPlanContainer, new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/jmxFile.jmx"));

    Summariser summariser = new Summariser("summaryOfResults");
    ResultCollector resultCollector = new ResultCollector(summariser);
    ...
    testPlanContainer.add(testPlanContainer.getArray()[0], resultCollector);
    ...
```

I believe my mistake is somewhere around the JsonPostProcessor, maybe I should use another class or another way how to extract, store and invoke data from one request to another.
Will appreciate any advice

Comment: Why do you need HTTPSampler to execute HTTP requests? Why dont use HttpClient to send request and receive response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to help you without seeing your `set details` implementation, in order to add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of a Sampler you need to add both to a [HashTree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html), then add this HashTree to the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)'s HashTree, add Thread Group's HashTree to [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)'s HashTree, etc.

Example minimal working code would be something like:

```
// JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

// First HTTP Sampler - open jsonplaceholder.typicode.com and extract id
HTTPSamplerProxy jsonplaceholderSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
jsonplaceholderSampler.setDomain("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
jsonplaceholderSampler.setPort(80);
jsonplaceholderSampler.setPath("/todos/1");
jsonplaceholderSampler.setMethod("GET");
jsonplaceholderSampler.setName("HTTP Request - get id");
jsonplaceholderSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
jsonplaceholderSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

JSONPostProcessor jsonPostProcessor = new JSONPostProcessor();
jsonPostProcessor.setName("JSON Extractor");
jsonPostProcessor.setProperty("JSONPostProcessor.referenceNames", "cart-id");
jsonPostProcessor.setProperty("JSONPostProcessor.jsonPathExprs", "$.id");
jsonPostProcessor.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JSONPostProcessor.class.getName());
jsonPostProcessor.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, JSONPostProcessorGui.class.getName());


// Second HTTP Sampler - open example com
HTTPSamplerProxy exampleComSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
exampleComSampler.setDomain("example.com");
exampleComSampler.setPort(80);
exampleComSampler.setPath("/${cart-id}");
exampleComSampler.setMethod("GET");
exampleComSampler.setName("HTTP Request - send id");
exampleComSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
exampleComSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


// Loop Controller
LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
loopController.setLoops(1);
loopController.setFirst(true);
loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
loopController.initialize();

// Thread Group
ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

// Test Plan
TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

// Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
HashTree firstSamplerHashTree = new HashTree();
firstSamplerHashTree.add(exampleComSampler);
firstSamplerHashTree.add(jsonplaceholderSampler, jsonPostProcessor);
threadGroupHashTree.add(firstSamplerHashTree);
```

Check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui/) article for general information, you can also find some hints and code snippets in the comments section.

If you're not too comfortable with writing Java code using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) it might be easier to consider using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool which [provides possibility to build JMeter test plans programmatically using simple YAML syntax](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config).

Comment: Dear Dmitri, honestly I was hoping that you will help me with the answer, I read tons of your answers here and found them extremely useful. This one wasn't the exception, it helped) 
thank you again for sharing your expertise